# How can I calculate curvature of each point on a surface?

Tags: matlab, gradient, curve-fitting, curve, geometry-surface

I have a point cloud and I first draw surface of these points using matlab(by centering of points).
my points have 3D coordinates including (X,Y,Z). original of points are same:

```
    32512035.2100000    5401399.57000000    346.880000000000
32512044.0300000    5401399.54000000    346.850000000000
32512046.8900000    5401399.55000000    346.780000000000
32512049.7800000    5401399.53000000    346.860000000000
32512052.6900000    5401399.53000000    346.700000000000
32512054.0300000    5401399.53000000    346.780000000000
32512055.6900000    5401399.57000000    346.810000000000
32512063.1200000    5401399.54000000    347.800000000000
32512074.2300000    5401399.55000000    346.440000000000
32512093.1200000    5401399.54000000    346.660000000000
```

and centering of them are:

```
-28.7291900003911   -3.97948997747153   -0.700859999999409
-19.9091900000931   -4.00948997773230   -0.730859999999382
-17.0491900006891   -3.99948997795582   -0.800859999999432
-14.1591900000931   -4.01948997750878   -0.720859999999391
-11.2491899999441   -4.01948997750878   -0.880859999999416
-9.90919000009308   -4.01948997750878   -0.800859999999432
-8.24918999994407   -3.97948997747153   -0.770859999999402
-0.819190000242088  -4.00948997773230   0.219140000000607
10.2908099991619    -3.99948997795582   -1.14085999999941
29.1808099997579    -4.00948997773230   -0.920859999999379
```

and I draw surface using `fit` formula in matlab.

I want to calculate curvature of each point and try [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11168-surface-curvature) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10010-mean-curvature-fast-code/content/mcurvature_vec.m) but I can't understand "The inputs (X,Y,Z) are 2D arrays corresponding to the surface being analyzed." thing.
anybody to help me? or tell to me that how can I calculate curvature?

[image]

Comment: According to the comments at the beginning of the code (your second link), **"The matrices can be formed using meshgrid or similar functions."**

Comment: thanks. But when I build meshgrids, answers is NaN. all of elements.